# Output Buffering in Python Scripts Launched By PHP

Tags: php, python, apache, terminal

I've got a setup at the moment where I'm trying to call a python script which as been installed into the `/usr/share/` folder from a PHP script. When I call the script via this command:

```
proc_open('exec ' . escapeshellcmd($command))
```

The reason for running exec is to retrieve the actual PID rather than the child PID that proc_open returns. The goal is to return the output line by line and process it, for the most part this works, but when I just call the command globally, e.g., `$command = 'myscript';` the output buffers and delivers me a block when the program finishes. When I run the command `$command = 'python /usr/share/myscript.py';` I run into permission errors.

How can I run the global version (strongly preferred over the full path) and get the output line by line without buffering? Other programs work, it just seems to be python not delivering the output line by line without the explicit 'python' call.

Comment: `Idle` is `oslevel`, create an `sh` and add  as `sudoers` or valid user. Of course your  `sh` file include a `change_dir ; python your_script.py`